estimating preference rate
I'm offering an online service and want to determine how often people choose my service compared to my competitors. To estimate this, I have some data that tracks when users are presented with a list of services and which service they choose. This data comes from various sources (vendors). Hence I can calculate a source-specific preference rate.
The data I've collected is at the user level and organized by date. Here's an schema:
date, source, cust_id, os, demographics, #_my_service_chosen, #total_services_availaed
1/6, s1, 101, iOS, US, 7, 10
2/6, s1, 107, iOS, US, 3, 10
:::
8/6, s4, 707, iOS, UK, 13, 20

However, I know that the sources in my data aren't exhaustive and cover only about 20% of my entire user base. Additionally, the data is skewed: Source 1 (s1) accounts for roughly 80% of the sample, while the other sources contribute only 5% each.
Now given this biasedness in representation, less coverage of sample (20%); how can I reliably estimate the population preference rate?
Things I have already tried:

a baseline estimate using bootstrap sampling.
naive projection of sampling mix to population

What other methods can I explore? I am new to bayesian methods, and I'm considering a Bayesian hierarchical model, but would it make sense to apply this at the customer level, given that I have around 5 million records?

Are sources sampling some users, so you only see choices of the 20%? Or are there other sources with 80% of customers that are unseen where the preferences could differ?

@dimitriy its the later, there are other sources with 80% of customers that are unseen where the preferences could differ

Then you do have a sample with biased sampling. It is very difficult to construct an unbiased estimator for any population parameter. You could assume some patterns are common between the 1/5 in sample and 4/5 outside, some regression model coefficients for example, and predict the outcome in the 1/5 + 4/5 pseudo data by assuming certain predictor values in the 4/5 portion. You can also check out sample selection. See R package sampleSelection. But this requires a sample from the 4/5 group to know what determines sample entry.

It depends on what constitutes the population and what makes unit of analysis. I do not think bootstrap sampling or Bayesian model is the key. Instead, you need to understand how the sampling was done through the following procedures.

If what you call as the "user base" should be the population and you have a spreadsheet of all customers in the user base, then match the sample to the user base to assess its representativeness. Is the population all residents in a country? If so, you may want to explore "population synthesis" to weight observations so their marginal distribution align with the all residents in key attributes, such as sex, age, and income. Is the population all visitors to each vendor? If so, you need acquire a list of all customers from each vendor and weight observations accordingly.
Is the unit of analysis a person, an account, or a transaction? If the person, each customer should have at most one observation. For a transaction, a customer can have one or more records.
What was the data generating process? Were some person or account randomly selected to be given the alternatives? Were the alternatives presented to a customer or an account only once?
One does not claim that the data is skewed or the sampling is biased just because one group constitutes 80% of records. If 80% of customers use Vendor 1 and the population is all customers, the sample is representative. The 20% sample size relative to the population size is not concerning and might be very high in most applications. For example, the American Community Survey only surveys 1% of US populations over a year on detailed questions.

With the sampling procedures correctly understood, you could get an estimate of some parameter by properly weighing the observations in the sample if necessary.

The outcome variable is not presented as a binary indicator of whether a customer chooses the target service instead of a competitor's but a count of the target service is chosen along with the number of services available. It is unclear how a preference rate in this situation is measured and interpreted.
You may want to get familiar with multinomial regression (choose one option or rank multiple options among several alternatives), logistic regression of grouped data (out of several alternatives, how many were chosen), or logistic regression of binary outcome (was each alternative chosen or not if one could choose multiple) that are typical in discrete choice modeling.

